# Save the data to table and save it to database even if empty rows in EXCEL java POI Apache

Tags: java, excel, spring, spring-boot, apache-poi

I dont know how to save the content in database, I try to import the excel it works but if the excel one of the rows are empty it appears java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException

-- Here's my code --

-- BranchEntity.java --

public class Branch {

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Column(name = "branch_code", nullable = false, length = 10)
private String branchCode;

@Column(name = "branch_desc", nullable = false, length = 100)
private String branchDescription;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "branch", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JsonIgnore
private List<User> user;

public Branch(String branchCode, String branchDescription, List<User> user) {
    super();
    this.branchCode = branchCode;
    this.branchDescription = branchDescription;
    this.user = user;
}

public Branch() {
    super();
}

public String getBranchCode() {
    return branchCode;
}

public void setBranchCode(String branchCode) {
    this.branchCode = branchCode;
}

public String getBranchDescription() {
    return branchDescription;
}

public void setBranchDescription(String branchDescription) {
    this.branchDescription = branchDescription;
}

public List<User> getUser() {
    return user;
}

public void setUser(List<User> user) {
    this.user = user;
}
```

}

-- BranchService.java ---

@Autowired
   private BranchRepository branchRepository;

public List> uploadEmployee(MultipartFile multip) throws Exception {

```
    DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();

    String fileNames = multip.getOriginalFilename();

    File file = new File("./reports/" + fileNames);
    Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(file);

    FormulaEvaluator evaluator = workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();

    Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

    Supplier<Stream<Row>> rowStreamSupplier = uploadUtils.getRowStreamSupplier(sheet);

    Row headerRow = rowStreamSupplier.get().findFirst().get();
    List<String> headerCells = uploadUtils.getStream(headerRow)
    .map(Cell::getStringCellValue) 
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

    int colCount = headerCells.size();

    List<Map<String, String>> content = rowStreamSupplier.get()
    .skip(1)
    .map(row -> {

    List<String> cellList = uploadUtils.getStream(row)
    .map((cell) -> formatter.formatCellValue(cell, evaluator))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());  
        return uploadUtils.cellIteratorSupplier(colCount)
    .get()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(headerCells::get, cellList::get));
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());

    branchRepository.save(content);

    workbook.close();

    return content;

}
```

-- BranchController.java --

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadEmployee", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public List<Map<String, String>> uploadEmployee(MultipartFile file) throws Exception {
    return employeeService.uploadEmployee(file);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException` you need to avoid the `java.util.stream.*` approach since this fully depends on using `Iterator`s. But `apache poi`'s  Busy Developers' Guide -> [Iterate over rows and cells](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterator) tells:

> Note that a rowIterator and cellIterator iterate over rows or cells
>   that have been created, skipping empty rows and cells.

So empty rows and cells are not iterated. That's why getting a empty cell from a cellIterator is impossible and fails.

To avoid that we should do the following:

First collect the column headers as a `Map` of header names to column indexes. This can be done using a cell iterator over the first row. If cells are empty there, then this column will be skipped.

Then collect the content into your needed `List` of `Map`s where cell values are mapped to header names. This must be done for each row using a `for` loop from first header column index to last header column index. If cells are empty, then the cell can be created as empty cell. So `DataFormatter` gets it's value as empty string then.

Complete working example:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.*;

public class ReadExcelToCollection {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();

  File file = new File("Excel.xlsx");
  Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(file);

  FormulaEvaluator evaluator = workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();

  Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

  int headerRowNum = sheet.getFirstRowNum();

  // collecting the column headers as a Map of header names to column indexes
  Map<Integer, String> colHeaders = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
  Row row = sheet.getRow(headerRowNum);
  for (Cell cell : row) {
   int colIdx = cell.getColumnIndex();
   String value = formatter.formatCellValue(cell, evaluator);
   colHeaders.put(colIdx, value);
  }

  System.out.println(colHeaders);

  // collecting the content into List of Maps where cell values are mapped to header names.
  List<Map<String, String>> content = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
  for (int r = headerRowNum + 1; r <= sheet.getLastRowNum(); r++) {
   row = sheet.getRow(r); if (row == null) row = sheet.createRow(r);
   Map<String, String> valuesToHeaders = new HashMap<String, String>();
   for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : colHeaders.entrySet()) {
    int colIdx = entry.getKey();
    Cell cell = row.getCell(colIdx); if (cell == null) cell = row.createCell(colIdx);
    String cellValue = formatter.formatCellValue(cell, evaluator);
    valuesToHeaders.put(entry.getValue(), cellValue);
   }
   content.add(valuesToHeaders);
  }

  System.out.println(content);

  workbook.close();
 }
}
```

Comment: Amazing Sir @Axel thank you for resolving not empty rows but I have a problem how to insert it the content to Object in Branch in short converting map to object? To save it to database? Do you know spring sir @Axel?

Comment: @Bryan Caliwag: You was told already how Stackoverflow works. **One** question per question block. **Not** multiple questions per question block. And in no case: I've put some code in the question block. Please do my work for me now. As far as i see, the `branchRepository.save(content);` should do the insert the content to `Branch` objects, shouldn't it?

Comment: Yes sir @Axel it must save to Branch, Okay I will create another question Thank you very much I appreciate your effort ^_^