# Java.lang.StackOverflowError Excel in spring boot jpa

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, apache-poi

I have a problem I dont know how to track the StackOverFlowError it says And the converting to datatypes is okay but I dont know what the error comes from: How to fix this issue? Can you please help what is the most approach to track this error to generate the list and save it to database?

```
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at com.pioneer.ams.backend.entity.AbstractEntity.toString(AbstractEntity.java:178)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:462)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.toString(PersistentBag.java:510)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
```

Here's my code:

-- EmployeeService.java --

```
@Autowired
private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

public List<Map<String, String>> uploadEmployee(MultipartFile multip) throws Exception {

String fileNames = multip.getOriginalFilename();

DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();

File file = new File("./reports/" + fileNames);
Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(file);

FormulaEvaluator evaluator = workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();

Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

int headerRowNum = sheet.getFirstRowNum();

Map<Integer, String> colHeaders = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
Row row = sheet.getRow(headerRowNum);
for (Cell cell : row) {
    int colIdx = cell.getColumnIndex();
    String value = formatter.formatCellValue(cell, evaluator);
    colHeaders.put(colIdx, value);
}

  List<Employee> content = new ArrayList<>();
  for (int r = headerRowNum + 1; r <= sheet.getLastRowNum(); r++) {
   row = sheet.getRow(r);
   if (row == null)
      continue;
   Employee employee = new Employee();
   for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : colHeaders.entrySet()) {
    int colIdx = entry.getKey();
    Cell cell = row.getCell(colIdx);
    if (cell != null) {
        String cellValue = formatter.formatCellValue(cell, evaluator);
        switch(entry.getValue()) {
             case "lastname": {
                  employee.setLastName(cellValue);
                  break;
             }
             case "firstname": {
                  employee.setFirstName(cellValue);
                   break;
             }
             case "mi": {
                  employee.setMiddleInitial(cellValue);
                   break;
             }
             case "rank": {
                  employee.setRank(cellValue);
                   break;
             }
             case "emp_id": {
                  employee.setEmpId(cellValue);
                   break;
             }
             case "po_company_id": {
                 POCompany poCompanyId = poCompanyRepository.findById(Long.parseLong(cellValue));
                  employee.setPoCompany(poCompanyId);
                  break;
             }
             case "business_id": {
                 Business businessId = businessRepository.findById(Long.parseLong(cellValue));
                  employee.setBusiness(businessId);
                   break;
             }
             case "department_id": {
                 Department departmentId = departmentRepository.findById(Long.parseLong(cellValue));
                  employee.setDepartment(departmentId);
                   break;
             }
             case "status_id": {
                 Status statusId = statusRepository.findById(Long.parseLong(cellValue));
                  employee.setStatus(statusId);
                   break;
               }
          }
          employeeRepository.save(employee);
       }
    }
    content.add(employee);
}

workbook.close();

System.out.println(content);

return content;
}
```

-- Employee.java --

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
public class Employee extends AbstractEntity<Long> {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Column(name = "lastname", length = 200)
private String lastName;

@Column(name = "firstname")
private String firstName;

@Column(name = "mi")
private String middleInitial;

@Column(name = "rank", nullable = true)
private String rank;

@Column(name = "emp_id")
private String empId;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "po_company_id")
private POCompany poCompany;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "business_id")
private Business business;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "department_id")
private Department department;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "status_id")
private Status status;

public Employee() {
    super();
}

public Employee(String empId, String lastName, String firstName, String middleInitial, String rank,
        List<User> user) {
    this();
    this.empId = empId;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.middleInitial = middleInitial;
    this.rank = rank;
    this.user = user;
}

public String getEmpId() {
    return empId;
}

public void setEmpId(String empId) {
    this.empId = empId;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getMiddleInitial() {
    return middleInitial;
}

public void setMiddleInitial(String middleInitial) {
    this.middleInitial = middleInitial;
}

public String getRank() {
    return rank;
}

public void setRank(String rank) {
    this.rank = rank;
}

public Department getDepartment() {
    return department;
}

public void setDepartment(Department department) {
    this.department = department;
}

public Status getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(Status status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public Business getBusiness() {
    return business;
}

public void setBusiness(Business business) {
    this.business = business;
}

public void setBranch(Branch branch) {
 this.branch = branch;
}

public POCompany getPoCompany() {
    return poCompany;
}

public void setPoCompany(POCompany poCompany) {
    this.poCompany = poCompany;
}
}
```

-- EmployeeController.java --

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadEmployee", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<List<Employee>> uploadEmployee(MultipartFile file) throws Exception{

    return new ResponseEntity<List<Employee>>(employeeService.uploadEmployee(file), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Comment: have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/56477233/8112217

Answer (score 2):

You are facing the issue probably because you are returning the `Employee.class` entity object directly from your endpoint.In your Employee Entity class you have 
`@ManyToOne` relations with several tables.So, Jpa will resolve all these relations and populate the fields. In your `Business.class` or other entity class that you used in your code , you might be having a bi-directional relation mapping to the Employee. So , when Jackson tries to convert this class to a json it might be causing the StackOverflow error as a result of the Infinite reference.

Use annotations like `@JsonBackReference` and `@JsonManagedBackReference` to prevent infinite loop in your entity class returned.The better approach being to create a DTO object and map the entity fields to the DTO object and return the DTO object from the endpoint.

> ```
> `@JsonManagedReference` is the forward part of reference – the one that gets serialized normally.
> `@JsonBackReference` is the back part of reference – it will be omitted from serialization.
> ```

If this did not help, please provide more details like the entire stacktrace, as well as the entity classes referenced in `Employee` entity class.
Read [Guide](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion).

Answer (score 1):

The error is pretty clear:

> at
>   com.pioneer.ams.backend.entity.AbstractEntity.toString(AbstractEntity.java:178)

So you have a `toString()` implementation that creates a circular loop i.e.

```
A.toString(){
    //references B.toString();
}

B.toString(){
    //references A.toString();
}
```